# Python subprocess.call and a list of arguments

Tags: php, python, list, subprocess

First post here but have been here many times while searching for answers.

I have finished my first coding book and am looking to add some functionality to a program I am writing.  I am trying to pass a list where each numbers is one argument send to a PHP file.

This is the test code that I have been looking at.

```
import subprocess

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] #Eventual variable length list of arguments
args = ','.join(str(e) for e in list1) #Convert list to string

print(str1) #Print to screen

subprocess.call(["php","-f","/var/www/html/test.php", args]) #Send
```

This sends the data to a PHP file that looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// Loop through each element in the $argv array
foreach($argv as $value)
{
  echo "$value\n";  // Print each argument to terminal
}
?>
```

When it runs I get this result. 
1,2,3,4

If I run it with the process call looking like this,

```
subprocess.call(["php","-f","/var/www/html/test.php", str(1),str(2),str(3),str(4)])
```

I get each of the numbers on a separate line (I think signifying that each is a new argument.)

How do I make it so that the subprocess.call will accept a list of arguments and actually have each comma-separated value be it's own argument?

EDIT
Eventually, I will be using this to submit a variable list of sensor values to a server.

EDIT #2

Dang it.  I did not realize till the post was marked as duplicate that the subprocess.call was working with a list.  Makes a bunch more sense now.

Problem is that the subprocess.call is looking for a string lists where I have a string list and a integer list.

EDIT #3
Eventual correct solution if anyone cares.

```
import subprocess

list1 = [1.45736478, 2.234544, 3.87655, 4.99967]
args = [str(x) for x in list1]
print(args)

subprocess.call(["php","-f","/var/www/html/test.php"] + args)
```

Gives me a list of string values and outputs the values each on their own line.

Modified my other program based on what was here and it is running great.  Thanks.

Comment: what ` is doing after `...args])`

Comment: Why not pass `["php","-f","/var/www/html/test.php"] + ['1', '2', '3', '4']` to `.call()`?

Comment: Each arg needs to be a separate element within the list.  So, `subprocess.call(["php","-f","/var/www/html/test.php"] + [str(e) for e in list1])`

Comment: curious about the php and python to solve this problem?

Comment: Eventually I am going to have it so that the list is variable (anywhere from 7 to 17 values depending on the sensors used)